# C# Collatz - Does anyone know a fix?

Tags: c#

Hey does anyone have a fix for this? I don't know why i keep getting an error that the main-cs and compilation fails.

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Length of Collatz Row");
    int cn = Console.ReadLine();
    CollatzListLength(cn);
  }

  public int CollatzListLength(n){
    int number;
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    while(n != 1){

      if(n % 2 == 0){
        number = n/2;
      }

      if(n%2 ==1){
        number = n*3 + 1;
      }
    n = number;
    numbers.Add(number);
    }
    return numbers.Count;
  }
```

Comment: What does the function Console.ReadLine return?

Comment: The next time please quote the exact error you get instead of just saying "an error".

Answer (score 3):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`, not an int.

`CollatzListLength` needs to be `static` and the parameter needs to be declared as `int`

`n = number;` doesn't work because `number` may never be assigned a value. Use `else` instead of `if (n % 2 == 1)` as it just checks the other possible condition anyway.

In total:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Length of Collatz Row");
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int cn))
        CollatzListLength(cn);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Needs a number");
}
public static int CollatzListLength(int n)
{
    int number;
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    while (n != 1)
    {

        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            number = n / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            number = n * 3 + 1;
        }
        n = number;
        numbers.Add(number);
    }
    return numbers.Count;
}
```

I haven't actually checked the sanity of the code though.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, repaired to compile without error messages:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Length of Collatz Row");
        int cn = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int len = CollatzListLength(cn);

        Console.WriteLine($"len {len}");
    }

    public static int CollatzListLength(int n)
    {
        int number = 0;
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        while (n != 1)
        {

            if (n % 2 == 0)
            {
                number = n / 2;
            }

            if (n % 2 == 1)
            {
                number = n * 3 + 1;
            }
            n = number;
            numbers.Add(number);
        }
        return numbers.Count;
    }
}
```